# Value of integral of $f$ on positive oriented circle radius $2$ around $1$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ $ \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic function. Let's assume that 
>   integral on positive oriented circle radius $1$ around $0$ is $2\pi$i. Find what is
>   value of integral of $f$ on positive oriented circle radius $2$ around $1$?

My idea was to use Cauchy theorem for star shape domain but is $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ star shape domain?

Comment: If you left i upright intentionally, you can use `\mathrm i` $\mathrm i$ instead

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) to show that the integrals are equal: Both integrals are equal to
$$
 \int_{\gamma_j} f(z) \, dz = 2 \pi i I({\gamma_j}, 0) \operatorname{Res}(f, 0) = 2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}(f, 0)
$$
because both circles have the same *winding number* $I({\gamma_j}, 0) = 1$ with respect to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach doen't work, since $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is *not* a star-shaped domain. But you can still apply [Cauchy's integral theorem](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jxr57/501-03/lecture8.pdf) and deduce from it that those integrals take the same value ($2\pi i$, in this case), since those paths are homotopic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. In fact, if $C$ is the  positive oriented circle with radius $1$ around $0$ and if its domain is $[a,b]$ (for instance, you can take $a=0$, $b=2\pi$, and $C(t)=e^{it}$), then$$\begin{array}{rccc}H\colon&[a,b]\times[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\\&(t,u)&\mapsto&(u+1)C(t)+u\end{array}$$is a homotopy between $C$ and the  positive oriented circle with radius $2$ around $0$.

Comment: What is your definition of a star-shaped domain? Unless I am mistaken, start-shaped domains are simply connected.

Comment: @Jose Can you please be more explicit?

Comment: @MartinR My mistake. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Can you please explain how to apply Cauchy's integral theorem?

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: It should be $H(t, u) = (u+1)C(t) + u$ because the second circle has the center $1$.

Comment: @MartinR Oops! Right, once again. I missed that. Thank you.